# mysql - хранение суммы заказа

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть две цены заказа, до определенной даты и после определенной даты (меньше, больше). И также можно редактировать сумму заказа, в бд храниться общая сумма заказа. Но если удалить после определенной даты, тогда сумма уйдет в минус.

То есть была два товара по 5000 : сумма 10000, после решил удалить товар, но стоимость его увеличилась в два раза, удаляет один товар 10 000 - 10 000 = 0 и по итогу можно брать за бесплатно один товар, подождав время. То есть если хранить в базе сумму заказа, тогда нужно хранить и время покупки, чтобы сравнивать время, я правильно понимаю?

То есть нужен совет, как правильно хранить в бд сумму заказа, чтобы потом не было проблем за бесплатный товар

Comment: *но стоимость его увеличилась в два раза* В момент любого изменения должна была быть пересчитана сумма заказа. Не откорректирована, а именно пересчитана, в соответствии с исправленным составом заказа и актуальными стоимостями товаров. А если кто-то сделал иначе, то ему и разгребать получившийся бред. За свой счёт.

Comment: имеется ввиду клиент может редактировать, после той даты, когда сумма возрастает и если  товар удалит уйдет сумма текущая ,которая в два раза больше. Я может не правильно объяснил,  но нужен совет по тому как правильно хранить ?

Comment: Повторяю. Не КОРРЕКТИРОВАТЬ, а именно ПЕРЕСЧИТЫВАТЬ. Давно: два товара по 5000, сумма 10000. Сейчас: хоть цена и изменилась, но состояние заказа зафиксировано. Если откорректировать заказ и удалить один товар, то в заказе останется один товар с ценой 5000, и при пересчёте получится стоимость заказа в 5000. Иными словами, при пересчёте стоимости заказа всё, что было раньше - цены, стоимость и пр.,- херится и считается от нуля, словно заказ только что сформирован. А по-хорошему, вообще надо удалять старый заказ и формировать новый.

Comment: все понял, спасибо

Comment: @Akina Я так понимаю, что проблема в следующем: в корзине два товара со стоимостью 5000 и 7000. Потом цена на ОБА выросла в два раза. Пользователь удалил один за 5000. Сумма заказа должна стать не 14000, как при пересчете, а 7000

Comment: да, то есть было 5 000 + 7 000 = 12 000. Цена выросла нужно отнять семь, а пока отниматься будет 14 000, то есть -2 000. И таким образом они ещё должны будут))

Comment: Да просто заведи таблицу "цена товара в заказе" и храни в ней цену товара на момент попадания в заказ. Тогда и сумму заказа хранить не надо - считай на лету. Ещё в заказе может быть один товар более одного раза, но с разной ценой, то храни в этой новой таблице ещё и кол-во товара по этой цене.